# Woocomerce - Variações não aparecem nos detalhes do Pedido

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Boa Tarde

Estou finalizando um projeto de uma loja virtual com Woocomerce.

Cadastrei o produto e suas variaveis, faço a escolha das variaveis (quantidade de controles e cor dos controles), vou para a página do carrinho (/cart).

Lá exibe o produto e suas variações, prossigo para o checkout e também são exibidas as opções escolhidas.

Quando finalizo a compra, se vou na aba "visualizar pedido", aparece o nome dos produtos, o nome das variações, porém não aparece as variações selecionadas.

E também não recebo as variações selecionados no e-mail de pedido, alguem consegue me ajudar?

Obrigado

Comment: Você esta usando um tema personalizado ou um daqueles prontos?

Comment: Estou usando o QShop (tema comprado). Porém já fiz o teste com o tema twenty twelve e não exibe do mesmo jeito.